# Facing Error in my Android App: RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am going to create Holy Quran App.

I created layout, I am using Recycler view in this app, for this I create sample file for all complete sorahs (114) and also creaeted a sample file for how a particular sorah will look like in User interface.

I created 2 Models(QuranModel and SorahModel) and 2 Adapter(QuranAdapter and SorahAdapter) for this purpose. Below are the details for Adapters and Models

**Quran Activity.java**

```
package com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Adapters.QuranAdapter;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Classes.RecyclerItemClickListener;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Models.QuranModel;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.databinding.ActivityQuranBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuranActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityQuranBinding binding;
    RecyclerView quranrecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityQuranBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        ArrayList<QuranModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add (new QuranModel(R.drawable.fatiha, "Sorah Al-Fatiha", "1", "7"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.albaqarah, "Sorah Baqarah", "286", "40"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.aaleimran, "Sorah Aale Imran", "200", "20"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annisa, "Sorah Nisa", "176", "24"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.maidah, "Sorah Maidah", "120", "16"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alanaam, "Sorah Anam", "165", "20"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alaaraf, "Sorah A'araf", "206", "24"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alanfaal, "Sorah Anfal", "75", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attaubah, "Sorah Taubah", "120", "16"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.younus, "Sorah Younus", "109", "11"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.hud, "Sorah Hud", "123", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.yousuf, "Sorah yousuf", "111", "12"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.arraad, "Sorah Ra'ad", "43", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.ibrahim, "Sorah Ibrahim", "52", "7"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alhijr, "Sorah Hijr", "99", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annahal, "Sorah Nahal", "128", "16"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alisra, "Sorah Isra ", "111", "12"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alkahaf, "Sorah Kahaf", "110", "12"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.mariyam, "Sorah Maryam", "98", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.tuaha, "Sorah Taha", "135", "8"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alanbiya, "Sorah Anbiya", "112", "7"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alhaj, "Sorah Hajj", "78", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almominun, "Sorah Momineen", "118", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annur, "Sorah Nur", "64", "9"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alfurqan, "Sorah Furqan", "77", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.ashshuara, "Sorah Shu'ara", "227", "11"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annaml, "Sorah Namal", "93", "7"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alqasas, "Sorah Qasas", "88", "9"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alankabut, "Sorah Ankabut", "69", "7"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.arrum, "Sorah Room", "60", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.luqman, "Sorah Luqman", "34", "4"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.assajda, "Sorah Sajda", "30", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alahzab, "Sorah Ahzaab", "73", "9"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.saba, "Sorah Saba", "54", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.fatir, "Sorah Fatir", "45", "5"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.yasin, "Sorah Yasin", "83", "5"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.assafaat, "Sorah Saaffaat", "182", "5"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.saad, "Sorah Saad", "88", "5"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.azzumur, "Sorah Zamar", "75", "8"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.ghafir, "Sorah Ghafir", "85", "9"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.fusilat, "Sorah Fussilat", "54", "6"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.ashshora, "Sorah Shurah", "53", "5"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.azzukhruf, "Sorah Zukhraf", "89", "7"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.addukhan, "Sorah Dukhan", "59", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.aljathiya, "Sorah Jasiya", "37", "4"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alahqaf, "Sorah Ahqaaf", "35", "5"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.muhammad, "Sorah Muhammad", "38", "4"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alfateh, "Sorah Fateh", "29", "5"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alhujrat, "Sorah Hujraat", "18", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.qaaf, "Sorah Qaaf", "45", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.azzariyat, "Sorah Az-Zariat", "60", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attur, "Sorah Tur", "49", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annajam, "Sorah Najam", "62", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alqamar, "Sorah Qamar", "55", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.arrehman, "Sorah Rehman", "78", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alwaqia, "Sorah Waqia", "96", "4"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alhadeed, "Sorah Hadeed", "29", "4"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almujadilah, "Sorah Mujadila", "22", "4"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alhashar, "Sorah Hashr", "24", "4"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almumtahina, "Sorah Mumtahana", "13", "3"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.assaf, "Sorah Saff", "14", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.aljuma, "Sorah Jum'a", "11", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almunafiqun, "Sorah Munafiqeen", "11", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attaghabun, "Sorah Taghabun", "18", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attalaq, "Sorah Talaq", "12", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attehreem, "Sorah Tehreem", "12", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almulk, "Sorah Mulk", "30", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alqalam, "Sorah Qalam", "52", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alhaqah, "Sorah Haaqqa", "52", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almaarij, "Sorah Ma'arij", "44", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.nuh, "Sorah Nooh", "28", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.aljin, "Sorah Jinn", "28", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almuzammil, "Sorah Muzammil", "20", "2"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almudathir, "Sorah Muddassir", "56", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alqayamat, "Sorah Qiyamah", "40", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alinsaan, "Sorah Al-Insaan", "31", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almursalat, "Sorah Mursalaat", "50", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annaba, "Sorah Naba", "40", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annaziat, "Sorah An-Naaziat", "46", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.abasa, "Sorah Abasa", "42", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attakweer, "Sorah Takweer", "29", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alinfitar, "Sorah Infitar", "19", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almutafifeen, "Sorah Mutaffifeen", "36", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alinshiqaq, "Sorah Inshiqaq", "25", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alburuj, "Sorah Burooj", "22", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attariq, "Sorah Tariq", "17", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alala, "Sorah A'ala", "19", "10"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alghashiya, "Sorah Ghashia", "26", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alfajr, "Sorah Fajr", "30", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.albalad, "Sorah Balad", "20", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.ashshams, "Sorah Shams", "15", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.allayl, "Sorah Al-Lail", "21", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.azzuha, "Sorah Zuha", "11", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.inshirah, "Sorah Inshirah", "8", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.atteen, "Sorah Teen", "8", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alalaq, "Sorah Alaq", "19", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alqadar, "Sorah Qadr", "5", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.albayinah, "Sorah Bayyinah", "8", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.azzalzalah, "Sorah Zalzalah", "8", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.aladiyat, "Sorah Adiyat", "11", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alqariya, "Sorah Al-Qariah", "11", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.attakathur, "Sorah Takasur", "8", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alasr, "Sorah Asr", "3", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alhumazah, "Sorah Humaza", "9", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alfeel, "Sorah Feel", "5", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.quraysh, "Sorah Quraish", "4", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almauoon, "Sorah Maoon", "7", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alkausar, "Sorah Kausar", "3", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alkafirun, "Sorah Kafiroon", "6", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annasar, "Sorah Nasr", "3", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.almasad, "Sorah Masad", "5", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alikhlas, "Sorah Ikhlas", "4", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.alfalaq, "Sorah Falaq", "5", "1"));
        list.add(new QuranModel(R.drawable.annaas, "Sorah Naas", "6", "1"));

        QuranAdapter quranAdapter = new QuranAdapter(list, this);
        binding.quranRecyclerView.setAdapter(quranAdapter);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        binding.quranRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        quranrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.quranRecyclerView);

        binding.quranRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener
                (this, quranrecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        switch (position)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(QuranActivity.this, FatihaActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                intent = new Intent(QuranActivity.this, BaqarahActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                intent = new Intent(QuranActivity.this, AaleImranActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                break;
                            default:
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    }
                }


                ));


    }
}
```

**QuranAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.BaqarahActivity;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.FatihaActivity;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Models.QuranModel;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuranAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuranAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<QuranModel> list;
    Context context;

    public QuranAdapter(ArrayList<QuranModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.quran_sorah_list_sample, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        QuranModel quranModel = list.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageResource(quranModel.getImage());
        holder.name.setText(quranModel.getName());
        holder.ruku.setText(quranModel.getRuku());
        holder.verses.setText(quranModel.getVerses());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image, imageInSample;
        TextView name , ruku , verses, nameInSample, contentsInSample ;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sorahImage);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSorahName);
            ruku = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRukus);
            verses = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVerses);

        }
    }
}
```

**SorahAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.BaqarahActivity;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Models.SorahModel;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SorahAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SorahAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<SorahModel> list;
    Context context;

    public SorahAdapter() {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sorah_sample, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SorahModel sorahModel = list.get(position);
        holder.imageInSample.setImageResource(sorahModel.getImage());
        holder.nameInSample.setText(sorahModel.getName());
        holder.contentsInSample.setText(sorahModel.getContents());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageInSample;
        TextView nameInSample, contentsInSample;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageInSample = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageInSample);
            nameInSample = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameInSample);
            contentsInSample = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentsInSample);
        }
    }
}
```

**BaqarahActivity.xml**

Below is the XML file for which i created for my 2nd Sorah of Quran.

[image]

**Sorah_sample.xml**

below is the sorah_sample for which i created for Models and Adapters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.BaqarahActivity;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.Models.SorahModel;
import com.example.app.androiddevelopment.islam.R;

class SorahAdapter (
    var items: List<SorahModel>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SorahAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {
    class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.sorah_sample, parent, false)
        return ListViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItems = items[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
        nameInSample.text = currentItems.getName()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }
}
```